# How to properly embed HTML code in PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress

For a Wordpress plugin, I made a function that contains a big HTML portion (following [WP docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), I used `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` to insert it):

```
function myShortcode() {

   ob_start();?> 

    <!-- here a lot of HTML -->

    <?php
        return ob_get_clean();

}
```

I would like to put the HTML outside this function and `include` or `require` it.

Is this possible? Is there something I should be aware of? Is it preferable `file_get_contents`? Any other tip is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can move your html to separate file and then include it as simple php file after ob_start()... Yes it will work, just make sure your view.php template partial is Echoing that html, i.e. You may have html outside of php tags e.g.

File view.php

```
     <?php //Template code starts ?>

      ALL HTML HERE

    <?php // Template code ends ?>
```

And your current function in current plugin php file will become:

```
 function myShortcode() {

               ob_start();
               include(PLUGIN_DIR_PATH/templates/view.php);
               return ob_get_clean();

            }
```

Comment: Echoing as a echo "big html string"? That is: I can't insert it as raw HTML?

Comment: @3000 You can as raw html, no need to Echo, see I have closed php tags, so you can insert HTML as RAW html, i just made it .php file so if you need to have any php variables inside html for data like <h2><?= $title ?></h2> for it to work in raw html, you need to have php file.. hence view.php...